# Combine items in a 2D array based on the header column

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array

We need to download the list of items from server everyday, the server gives the groceries list. Some items are of no use for us as we don't sell them.

Some are needed and we specify them by `array = columnHeadingsNeeded`
We need to process the downloaded raw list and generate a 2d array for Google sheet and that would look like
columnHeadingsNeeded may vary over time and hence we keep them in an array.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18FSwIDZ5H5nqrbwq-VIMoHouW6f0cSZ7sTIgN9RxBc0/edit?usp=sharing

[image: Click to see the expected results]

We need to combine the specified categories of items and have a 2d array for populating to Google sheet

Hence the end result is nothing but 2d array as shown in the image

I have tried with

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <script>
    //*******************INPUTS BY USER***************************/
    //input from user
    var combineHeaderData = ["fruits"]; //this will change everyday it can be berries or only vegetables or both and combination and so on
    //input from user
    var columnHeadingsNeeded = [
      "fruits 1",
      "fruits 2",
      "fruits 3",
      "fruits 4",
      "fruits 5",
      "vegetables 1",
      "vegetables 2"
    ]

    //*******************END INPUTS BY USER***************************/


    //.....
    //ajax code here that downloads the response from server everyday
    //......
    //.......
    var downloadedJSON = [{
        "vegetables 1": "carrot",
        "vegetables 2": "cabbage",
        "fruits 1": "banana",
        "fruits 2": "apple",
        "fruits 3": "orange",
        "nuts 1": "cashew"
      },
      {
        "vegetables 1": "beans",
        "fruits 1": "watermelon",
        "fruits 2": "apple",
        "fruits 3": "orange",
        "nuts 1": "cashew",
        "berries 1": "strawberry",
        "berries 1": "blueberry",
      }
    ]


    //*******************PROCESSING THE DISPLAY BASED ON INPUTS***************************/


    let table = downloadedJSON.map(f =>
      columnHeadingsNeeded.map(function(k) {
        return f[k] ?? ''
      })

    ).sort()

    table.unshift(columnHeadingsNeeded.map(function(k) {
      return k
    }))

    document.write(JSON.stringify(table))
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const downloadedJSON = download();
combine(downloadedJSON, ['fruits']);
combine(downloadedJSON, ['vegetables']);
combine(downloadedJSON, ['fruits', 'vegetables']);

function combine(data, combineHeaderData) {
  //input from user
  const columnHeadingsNeeded = [
    "fruits 1",
    "fruits 2",
    "fruits 3",
    "fruits 4",
    "fruits 5",
    "vegetables 1",
    "vegetables 2"
  ];
  const separator = {
    'fruits': '#',
    'vegetables': ', '
  };
  
  let headers = [];
  columnHeadingsNeeded.forEach(header => {
    const category = header.match(/.+(?= \d+)/)[0];
    for (const input of combineHeaderData) {
      if (headers.includes(category)) {
        return;
      }
      else if (input === category) {
        headers.push(category);
        return;
      }
    }
    headers.push(header);
  });
  
  const body = new Array(data.length).fill().map(e => []);
  data.forEach((row, i) => {
    for (const header of headers) {
      let value;
      if (!header.match(/\d$/)) {
        const keys = Object.keys(row).filter(key => key.match(/.+(?= \d+)/)[0] === header);
        const values = [];
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(row)) {
          if (keys.includes(key)) { values.push(value); }
        }
        value = values.join(separator[header]);
      }
      else {
        value = row[header] || '';
      }
      body[i].push(value);
    }
  });
  headers = headers.map(e => {
    if (e.match(/\d$/)) { return e; }
    else { return 'Combined ' + e; }
  });
  const result = [headers, ...body];
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
}
  
function download() {
  return [
    {
      "vegetables 1": "carrot",
      "vegetables 2": "cabbage",
      "fruits 1": "banana",
      "fruits 2": "apple",
      "fruits 3": "orange",
      "nuts 1": "cashew"
    },
    {
      "vegetables 1": "beans",
      "fruits 1": "watermelon",
      "fruits 2": "apple",
      "fruits 3": "orange",
      "nuts 1": "cashew",
      "berries 1": "strawberry",
      "berries 1": "blueberry",
    }
  ];
}
```

Comment: You are the Man!!!! Perfect. I have been posting this since 5 days in different use cases. Even the experts stumbled upon to answer. I really really appreciate and wish you the best future.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Besides, I have modified the keys of `separator`. Please have a check.